# Hide OracleDatabase credentials in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I'm connecting to an external Oracle Database with the example function that can be found [here](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#easyconnect)

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : "hr",
    password      : mypw,  // mypw contains the hr schema password
    connectString : "mydbmachine.example.com/orclpdb1"
  }
);
```

So, as you can see, my credentials would be 'exposed' to everyone who can access the code (maybe github repository or something).

Is there any way of hiding my username and password or making them confidential, or I just shouldn't worry about it?

Note: I'm using the oracledb node module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .env, and access to it with process.env.

check here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env

Answer (score 0):

Store your database secrets encrypted in [Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) or [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) and have your app read them at runtime. Be sure to update the IAM role that your app uses so that it has IAM permissions to retrieve the credentials.

Note: for [certain databases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-rds.html), Secrets Manager supports auto-rotation of credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Choices include:

1. prompt for the password at runtime
2. pass the password in an environment variable
3. use kerberos and then use ['external' authentication](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdbisexternalauth) in node-oracledb.  All this is configured and enabled in code layers below node-oracledb,  see the [Oracle Database Security Guide](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=DBSEG).
4. use an Oracle Wallet and then use 'external' authentication in node-oracledb.